How to customize user in negotiate response for serverless SignalR Service in Nodejs Azure function
I have Azure functions app written in Node.js, that uses Azure SignalR Service in serverless mode for some raal-time functionality. For clients to be able to connect to this SignaR Service, my Azure functions expose the standard /negotiate endpoint, which provides SignalR Service connection info as follows:
const inputSignalR = input.generic({
  type: "signalRConnectionInfo",
  name: "connectionInfo",
  hubName: "my-hub",
});

async function negotiate(request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext) {
  try {
    return { body: JSON.stringify(context.extraInputs.get(inputSignalR)) };
  } catch (error) {
    context.log(error);
    return {
      status: 500,
      jsonBody: error,
    };
  }
}

app.post("negotiate", {
  authLevel: "anonymous",
  handler: negotiate,
  route: "negotiate",
  extraInputs: [inputSignalR],
});

this works as expected - SignalR clients call the negotiate endpoint, from which they get SignalR Service connection info (url and access token) and they use those to connect to the SignalR Service. This is standard SignalR connection flow and it works without problems.
The issue comes when I want to make that generated access token in connection info aware of the user (in the above state it does not contain user identity and without it SignaR Service does not know what user is connected to it). I need that to be able to send SignalR messages to specfic users.
Since our Azure functions (including the SignalR specific /negotiate one) are already called with our standard JWT token in Authorization header (for which we already have shared logic to verify and parse the claims), I would like to take the user identifier claim from our JWT token and use it as user identifier in that connection info access token.
According to docs there are a few ways to augment the generated SignalR Service access token by using additional input binding properties/settings:

userId - with this property, you can tell the generated access token to use a header field or query parameter as user identifier for SignalR. This however does not solve my issue, as I want the user identity to be taken from incoming JWT token, not header/query param. There is a possibility that our SignalR clients would put their user identifiers into an agreed header or query parameter, but I don't want to do that, as than a SignalR client could pretend to be somebody else by putting someone else's user identifier into that agreed header/query param, which is a security risk. Also it's kind of weird duplication - the verified user identity is already present in JWT token that the clients are sending, so why put it in some additional field.
idToken + claimTypeList - with those properties it's possible to specify from where the incoming JWT token should be parsed (in our case its Authorization header) and which claims from it should be propagated to generated SignalR Service access token. This however does not help either as SignalR uses specific claim name (asrs.s.uid) in access token as user identifier. So even though I'm able to successfully propagate name, email and account_id claims from our JWT token into the SignalR access token, the SignalR does not recognize the user identity as it's not under expected claim name.

In documentation I found that this is doable in C#, using Azure SignalR Service Management SDK or using Azure SignalR Service function extension. Using either of those you can specify the user identity "manually" in the function body, before returning the connection info.
This is exactly what I would need, as the logic for verifying and obtaining user identity from our standard JWT token already exists in our code base, the only thing missing is how to push it to SignalR access token.
I could not find anything like it for NodeJS Azure functions. Is is even possible?

Could you please provide the error details, if you are receiving any?

There are no errors. I just want to know how to propagate user identy into SignalR using negotiate Azure function written in Nodejs. This is something thats doable using C#, but on how do do it using Nodejs I could not find any documentation or other resources.

In Node.js Azure Functions, there's no direct way to "inject" a user identifier from a JWT token into the SignalR access token like you can in C# using the SignalR Management SDK or function extensions.

Manually generate the SignalR Service connection info, including the user identifier from the JWT, by calling the Azure SignalR Service REST API for client negotiation.

Extract the user identifier from the JWT token passed in the Authorization header.
Call the Azure SignalR REST API to generate a token with the correct user identity. In this way, we can be able to control how the asrs.s.uid claim (used by SignalR to identify users) is added.
logic to extract and verify the JWT token and get the user identifier:
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function extractUserIdFromJwt(request) {
    const authHeader = request.headers['authorization'];
    if (!authHeader) throw new Error('No Authorization header found');

    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1]; // Assuming "Bearer <token>" format
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET); // Verify the JWT

    // Extract the user identifier from claims, e.g., 'sub' or another claim
    const userId = decodedToken.sub; // Assuming 'sub' is the user identifier
    return userId;
}

Manually create a connection info payload with the user identifier.
const axios = require('axios');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

async function negotiate(request, context) {
    try {
        const userId = extractUserIdFromJwt(request);  // Extract user from JWT
        const hubName = "my-hub"; // Your SignalR hub name
        const signalrAccessKey = process.env.SIGNALR_ACCESS_KEY;  // SignalR Access Key
        const signalrUrl = process.env.SIGNALR_URL;  // SignalR URL

        // Generate token manually with user ID
        const token = jwt.sign(
            {
                "asrs.s.uid": userId,  // Set user identifier
                "aud": `${signalrUrl}/client/hubs/${hubName}`,  // Audience
            },
            signalrAccessKey,
            {
                expiresIn: "1h",  // Token validity
                algorithm: "HS256",
            }
        );

        const connectionInfo = {
            url: `${signalrUrl}/client/?hub=${hubName}`,
            accessToken: token,
        };

        return { body: connectionInfo };
    } catch (error) {
        context.log(error);
        return {
            status: 500,
            jsonBody: error,
        };
    }
}


Console Log:
[INFO] Decoded JWT token: {
  "sub": "user123",
  "name": "Surya tej",
  "email": "Surya.tej@example.com",
  "iat": 1609459200,
  "exp": 1609462800
}
[INFO] User ID extracted from token: user123
[INFO] Generating SignalR access token with user ID: user123
[INFO] SignalR access token generated: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[INFO] Connection info being returned: {
  "url": "https://<your-signalr-service-url>/client/?hub=my-hub",
  "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}


hi, I somehow fail to see where this "calling the Azure SignalR Service REST API" you mention is happening.  Also where do you get the SignalR Service private key from to sign the JWT with?

Here is a similar issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/2056 and I've answered the question there. In short, you can use userId: {headers.X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME} to get the principle name, and {headers.X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID} to get the principle ID. If you have any other question, feel free to reply to that GitHub issue.

I am aware of thtat issue, as I am the author :D
aren't those headers you mention populated only when using some Azure supported authentication (MS Entra, Github etc)? As we are using custom third party Identity Provider, how would Azure know what claim from our JWT to put into those headers?
